# More/less trading on Mondays and Fridays?

Tags: trading, financial-markets

In market microstructure/high frequency finance, it is well known that the trading day has high activity in the opening hours and closing hours compared to mid-day. Can the same be said about the trading week, in that markets on Mondays and Fridays are more active than Wednesday as people open/close their positions at the start and end of the week?

Comment: Could you please start accepting answers to your questions?

Comment: Why don't you get some data and test it?

Comment: the trading day having high activity in the opening and closing hours compared to mid-day has become a stylized fact observed in hundreds of assets. I just want to see if the trading week also reflects as a stylized fact in the low-frequency theory

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is no impact on the volume of transactions depending on the day of the week if we refer to this chart: [https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-average-total-number-of-trades-daily-on-NASDAQ#:~:text=What%20is%20the%20average%20total%20number%20of%20trades%20daily%20on%20NASDAQ%3F,-ad%20b&text=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nasdaqtrader.com,daily%2C%20around%2010%20million%20trades](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-average-total-number-of-trades-daily-on-NASDAQ#:%7E:text=What%20is%20the%20average%20total%20number%20of%20trades%20daily%20on%20NASDAQ%3F,-ad%20b&text=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nasdaqtrader.com,daily%2C%20around%2010%20million%20trades).

[image: (the direct link to the graph is this one: https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-63dde1404e9a8ed991586ec1679068d3)]

The only "race" that exists is at the end of the year, and it lasts for the last days/weeks of the year.

Comment: I don't see chart from your link

Comment: you should expand the first "continue reading" button. But anyway, I added the image directly in the answer.